# shutil move based on csv filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi guys currently moving file based on filename on my csv file but it always move the files first and then read the filename so it always got error already exist like this

Error: Destination path 'Sortir/Membuka kertas contekan/aug1_Data16_133_86.jpg' already exists

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
filenames = data['filename'].values
filenames = filenames.tolist()
classes = data['class'].values
classes = classes.tolist()

print(filenames)
print(classes)
import shutil
import os

for index, row in data.iterrows():
  print(row['filename'], os.path.join("Sortir",row['class']))
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("Sortir",row['class'])):
    print("[INFO] 'creating {}' directory".format(os.path.join("Sortir",row['class'])))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join("Sortir",row['class']))
  shutil.move(os.path.join("images",row["filename"]), os.path.join("Sortir",row['class']))
```

Anyone know how to do the read the row first and then move the file? or maybe keep continue to read other row even if the file that I want to move being already moved?

**Found the Answer Code here :**

```
import shutil
import os
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
filenames = data['filename'].values
filenames = filenames.tolist()
classes = data['class'].values
classes = classes.tolist()

print(filenames)
print(classes)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("SortirTest",row['class'])):
    print("[INFO] 'creating {}' directory".format(os.path.join("SortirTest",row['class'])))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join("SortirTest",row['class']))
  input_name  = os.path.join("images", row["filename"])
  output_name = os.path.join("SortirTest", row['class'], row['filename'])
  if os.path.exists(input_name):
    dest = shutil.move(input_name, output_name)
    print("This File Has Been Moved:", input_name)
  else:
    print("This File Doesnt Exist :", input_name)
    continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shutil.move()` function you have to add the filename in the new directory too:

```
input_name  = os.path.join("images", row["filename"])
output_name = os.path.join("Sortir", row['class'], row['filename'])
shutil.move(input_name, output_name)
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help ! but its still have the same problem its still moving the item first before read the csv file:(

Comment: nvm, with a little more bit of touch its works thanks for giving some inspiration !

Comment: glad to hear that! could you edit your question with the solution that you apply, please (just for the record)

Comment: idk why i cant edit your answer, i just add some loop using os.path.exist and its done, sorry for late reply

Comment: No worries, I meant to edit your answer in the correct way

Comment: @JuniorPython Editing answers is probably not the way to go here. The request was to edit your _question_ with more details. But if your problem is solved now, probably let's all just move on.

Comment: @tripleee okayy, done, thank you for your suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the 'Sortir' folder before running the script?

Comment: i did its a new file so it has nothing inside

Comment: its just keep moving file first and then read the filename in csv file so it always said exist...